# Aurelia Webpack Use Environment Variables In index.ejs and/or webpack.config.js

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I have created an application that makes use of Google services. In order to properly lock down my API keys, I have restricted their use depending on the machine from where they are operating. With these restrictions, I have needed to create a separate development API key. The problem being that I now need to switch between which key my Aurelia app is using on build such that using `au build --env dev` will use the development Google API key and `au build --env prod` will use the production Google API key.

I'm rather familiar with adding environment variables in the `aurelia_project/environments/x.js` and using them in my `.js` classes via injection, however as Google script tags are found in the `index.ejs` file, I am unable to figure out how to get them in here.

E.g. In `index.ejs`

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<key binding here>&libraries=places"></script>
```

I notice there is a binding syntax in this same file of
`<%- htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.property_name>%>` which gets its value from the `webpack.config.js` file and I understand how it is made available via plugins namely

```
plugins: [
    ...
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'index.ejs',
      metadata: {
        // available in index.ejs //
        title, server, baseUrl //<- new property here
      }
    }),
```

But this still begs the question: How do I make this file aware of environment variables?

**Extra information:** I've tried moving the script tag to the `app.html` file but get loads of undefined errors on Google services, so it looks like I'm deeply restricted to having the script tag in the `index.ejs` file.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: in the `webpack.config.js` file you can use something like `const currentEnvconfig = require('./aurelia_project/environments/...');` based on the `env` flag.

Comment: @avrahamcool that did the trick. Thanks.